# HTML5 moving image, doesn't move

Tags: html5, webapp

Why my image doesn't move? Can you help me ...

```
<script>
   window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
      })();

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      ctx.font = 'bold 20pt Calibri';
      ctx.fillText('Traffic Light SIMULATION', 250, 25);

      function animate(imageObj, canvas, ctx, startTime) {
        // update
        var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

        var linearSpeed = 100;
        // pixels / second
        var newX = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

        if(newX < canvas.width - imageObj.width / 2) {
          imageObj.x = newX;
        }

        // request new frame
        requestAnimFrame(function() {
          animate(imageObj, canvas, ctx, startTime);
        });
      }      

    var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(imageObj.width,0);
        ctx.scale(-0.5,0.5);
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj,200,100);
        ctx.restore();
      };
      imageObj.src = 'car.png';

      setTimeout(function() {
        var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        animate(imageObj, canvas, ctx, startTime);
      }, 2000);

</script>
```

Comment: You could help us helping you by giving a more detailed description of the problem in plain text, along with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to draw the image at every frame when using canvas, you render the image once when calling `ctx.drawImage`, and thereafter you don't render anything to the canvas, so it stays the same.